# How to start a new scene while touchevent in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I am developing a small agme in android with libgdx. I placed an actor as button. I want to navigate to other screen while clicking on that actor. How is this possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a `InputListener` to your `Actor`:

```
actor.addListener( new InputListener {
    public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            game.setScreen(new OtherScreen());
            return true;
    }
});
```

Here you give the `Actor` an `InputListener` (there are many other methods you need to override). This `InputListener` reacts on touch down methods and if it is touched, you set the `game`s `Screen` (you need to have the `game` instance somewhere, so that you are able to set its `Screen`) to the `OtherScreen`.
The `Actor` must be `touchable` (`setTouchable(true)`) and `visible` (`setVisible(true)`), to recieve the `Event`s.

Hope it helps.